# How to add another class with jQuery if media query is less then 600px?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

Well I have listed some label, onClick of those label Im adding a class (`.circle-checked`), but if media query is less then `600px` then I dont want to be added this class (`.circle-checked`) but another class (`.circle-checked-blue`). How can I make this control !?

here is the code im using for know :

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('input').change(function(){
     var $this = $(this), $div = $('label.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default[for=' + $this.attr('id') + ']');
        if( $this.is(':checked') )
        {
            $div.addClass('circle-checked');
        }
        else
        {
            $div.removeClass('circle-checked');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

thanks

Comment: No, you rather don’t want that; at least if this is for styling purposes only. What you want, is to create rules in your stylesheet that format the element with the one single class you are going to use differently for different screensizes, using media queries.

Comment: And having _colors_ in class names is just terrible. If at some point someone decides this should not be blue any more, but green - then you have to either go switch out class names all over the project, or have a class that still says “blue” in the name, but actually uses green as a color. You should choose classes based on _meaning_ (what _state_ is this element currently in, that makes you want to give it a certain color?), not on currently desired formatting.

Comment: Don't add/remove classes for style/colours based on screen width - instead use `@media` in your css, eg: `.circle { color: red; } @media (max-width: 600px) { .circle { color: blue; } }`

Comment: The problem with a js solution is that you'll have to watch on window resize as well, and then maybe debounce it - all of which will be handled *efficiently* by the browser directly (even hardware accelerated in many cases) if you use css.

Comment: Actually, im having background images on label, then onClick, im adding the class .circle-checked which has has border, border-radius, height , width. and those images are complicated at mobile versin. So that @media 676 img display none, but onClick left border and border radius, and know I dont want to add them ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try `window.matchMedia` for this.

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $('input').change(function(){
         var $this = $(this), $div = $('label.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default[for=' + $this.attr('id') + ']');
            var classname='circle-checked';
             if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)').matches) {
                classname='circle-checked-blue';
             } 

            if( $this.is(':checked') )
            {
                $div.addClass(classname);
            }
            else
            {
                $div.removeClass(classname);
            }
        }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery width to get the width from the window...

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $('input').change(function(){
         var $this = $(this), $div = $('label.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default[for=' + $this.attr('id') + ']');

         var issm = $(window).width()=<600;
         var classChecked= issm?'circle-checked-blue':'circle-checked';


            if( $this.is(':checked') )
            {
                $div.addClass(classChecked);
            }
            else
            {
                $div.removeClass(classChecked);
            }
        }).change();
});
```